# Jekyll post 'belongs_to' post/collection object

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll is it possible to related a post to one or many specific posts or objects from a collection? And access their yaml data and content?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of exactly what you're trying to do I can only give you a general example.

You can use the ["where" filter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#filters)

```
{% assign  related_thing = site.[collection] | where: 'yaml_value', yaml_key %}
```

then run a for loop over `related_thing`

Hope that helps